# How to upload package to PyPi with Two Factor enabled?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, twine

I would like to upload a package to Pypi so I have created an account and tried to follow the manual.

1. Account:

It looks I cannot create projects from `pypi.org` directly:

[image]

2. I installed `twine` and I did

```
python3 -m twine upload dist/*
```

This time I have the following error:

```
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent 
authentication information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Perhaps this is related to my Two Factor Authentication. I am also curious about he `legacy` word used there.

If I disable the Two Factor Authentication it works...

Comment: As @phd mentioned, whether or not 2FA is enabled should have zero effect on uploads. Is it possible you mis-typed your username or password?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From https://pypi.org/help/#twofa:

Users who have chosen to set up two factor authentication will be asked to provide their second method of identity verification during the log in process. **This only affects logging in via a web browser, and not (yet) package uploads.**

You can use [API tokens](https://pypi.org/help/#apitoken) instead.

Comment: I didn't find how to create a project before uploading. Shall we create a global (account) token, upload with this token, then remove it and create a project token once the project is created?

Comment: @Jérôme https://stackoverflow.com/a/62535186/7976758

Comment: see the answer from @daniel-byrne for current method

Answer (score 19):

The same thing tripped me up.  When using 2FA, don't use you username.  Use instead `__token__` as your username.

For example:

```
[testpypi]
    username = __token__
    password = pypi-AgENdGVzdC5weXBpLm9yZwIkYTZkMjdmNDctNGFlNS00Y2U4LT
```

`__token__` isn't merely a placeholder for your username.  They actually want you to use `__token__` when authenticating with 2 factor.

Comment: What file does this go in again on linux?

Comment: @nialloc ~/.pypirc

Answer (score 0):

Since the start of 2024 Pypi requires 2FA.
There is a work around for API such as twine to be able to upload to pypi, this is called an API token.

To get twine working again to to pypi and log in. Go to Account settings and set up 2FA if you haven't already.
Scroll the the bottom of account settings and click "create API token". Name the token appropriatly and state its scope (If it effects one project or all).
You will then be shown the token name, ID, and value.
When uploading to pypi using twine next time us the username "**token**" and the pasword of the token **value**.
For example:

```
twine upload dist/* -u __token__ -p pypi-AgENdGVzdC5weXBpL...
```

I hope this helps.